# Reference request: Understanding Godement's criterion on quotient manifolds

Tags: smooth-manifolds, manifolds

I asked the same question on Math SE. If it is not appropriate to ask it here, I will delete it.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1925849/understanding-godements-criterion-on-quotient-manifolds

Let $X$ be a manifold and $R\subset X\times X$ be an equivalence relation. Let $X/R$ be the set of equivalence classes and let $p:X\rightarrow X/R$ be the projection. Give $X/R$ the quotient topology. It is known that there is at most one manifold structure on $X/R$ such that $p$ is a submersion. In page 92, of Serre's book "Lie algebras and Lie groups" Springer LNM 1500, there is a criterion for $X/R$ to be a manifold, which is named after Godement and says the following. The quotient $X/R$ is a manifold if and only if

1, $R$ is a sub manifold of $X\times X$ (which means $R\rightarrow X\times X$ is a closed embedding), and

2, the projection map $pr_2:R\rightarrow X$ is a submersion.

This criterion looks very powerful since it gives an iff condition. On the other hand, it also works for non-archimedean local fields. In the usual textbook on manifolds, there is a quotient theorem which requires the action is free and proper. The freeness seems too restrictive.

Since this criterion is not very common in the standard textbook on manifolds, I really would like to see how we apply this criterion to solve problems. Does anybody know a reference which contains a lot of examples on the application of this criterion?

I am also very interested in the following special case. Let $G$ be a compact Lie group which acts on a manifold $X$. Do we know that there exists a $G$-invariant open subset $X_o\subset X$ such that $X-X_o$ has lower dimension and $X_o/G$ exists as a manifold? Is this something standard from the Godement's criterion? How about when the field is non-archimedean?

In my other post, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1924189/quotient-of-textrmgl2-textbfr-by-the-conjugate-action-of-textrmso , I asked if the quotient $GL_2(R)/SO_2(R)$ exists as a manifold where $SO_2(R)$ acts on $GL_2(R)$ by conjugation. I got a nice answer from @YCor. But I also would like to know if it is possible to solve that problem using Godement's criterion.

The Godement's criterion is also mentioned in one answer of this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496571/under-what-conditions-the-quotient-space-of-a-manifold-is-a-manifold

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Serre says that "exists as a manifold" means "exists as a quotient manifold", which *by definition* requires $X\rightarrow X/R$ to be a submersion. That underlies the necessity of condition (2), which for $R=G\times X$ for an action by a discrete group $G$ on $X$ *forces* the action to be free. Thus, your statement that $\mathfrak{h}/{\rm{SL}}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ exists "as a manifold" is false in Serre's sense, so it is unclear what you seek since you are not being consistent with Serre's book. Godement's criterion is not as powerful as you think; it just expresses slickly something very concrete.

Comment: In practice, condition (1) is the hard part to verify: controlling the global structure of how $R$ sits inside $X\times X$ (such as for a group action); this is where conditions about "proper" group actions are lurking.  See 5.8 and 5.9 in Bourbaki's book on analytic varieties for more on this for analytic manifolds. In more robust theories of analytic spaces over non-archimedean fields (e.g., Berkovich spaces) there is an analogue of Godement's criterion but it is much harder to prove and has some surprises; see Theorem 1.2.2 and Remark 1.2.3 in https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.3441

Comment: ah, it is a surprise that $H\rightarrow H/SL_2(\textbf{Z})$ is not a submersion for the natural Riemann surface structure on the quotient $H/SL_2(\textbf{Z}) $.

Comment: It should not be a surprise: the "branch points" for that map of Riemann surfaces (i.e., points where it is not a local analytic isomorphism) correspond exactly to points of $\mathfrak{h}$ with non-trivial stabilizer group in ${\rm{SL}}_2(\mathbf{Z})/\langle -1 \rangle$.  (In particular, it would be more appropriate for you to use ${\rm{SL}}_2(\mathbf{Z})/\langle -1 \rangle$.)  This is the entire source of subtlety when making the appropriate Riemann surface structure on the quotient of $\mathfrak{h}$ by the action of a general arithmetic subgroup of ${\rm{PGL}}_2(\mathbf{Q})^+$.

Comment: Thanks for your nice comment. I am not familiar with the modular curve. But that is the first example which came in my mind that a quotient exists without requiring the action is free. I really want to know how can we compute the differential of the corresponding maps so that we can compute the "branch point" explicitly using Godement's criterion. I don't really understand your argument that condition (2) forces an action by a discrete group $G$ on $X$ to be free. What happened when the group is not discrete, say the adjoint action of $SO_2(R)$ on $SL_2(R)$?

Comment: I don't have time to get into this, but the situation of translation action by a closed subgroup of a Lie group is extremely special (and is discussed very completely in Bourbaki Lie groups Ch. 3).  Please talk with someone more local to you who is familiar with algebraic geometry. There is nothing deep in any of the above, just following one's nose with the definitions and being careful.

Comment: Thanks. But I need conjugation action.